# Open Source Social Bookmarking CMS?

Tags: open-source, content-management-system, bookmarks

I am looking for an open source social bookmarking site CMS so I can build a site like delicious with it for my organization. This will be deployed in the internal LAN.

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

SemanticScuttle is the best I've found: http://sourceforge.net/projects/semanticscuttle/

Answer (score 1):

i could suggest a site like www.rubysignal.com.
it works with django web framework, (rel 0.96).
The sources are on https://github.com/sebadima/bookmarks, but remember that it's just a alpha project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the tech you are using, but I've used [netlicious](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netlicious/) to use delicious itself as a CMS and then consume the bookmarks, descriptions etc on another website through the API.  If that makes sense.

Basically set up a delicious account and bookmark, tag and fill in the descriptions as you would normally.  And then hook in the neticious API into your own site - delicious stores everything and all you fundamentally have to do is consume an API.

Comment: I am open to any platform - LAMP/ .NET would do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Pligg is an open source CMS. http://www.pligg.com

Demo: http://www.pligg.com/demo/